# set custom form on visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, custom-controls

I want to change the default form control on on visual studio 2013. Not to edit a form after creating, but when i click on "add>>windows form" I want my custom form to show up, with the correct font and size and color scheme. Has anyone done this?

Comment: Create an item template.  File + Export Template.

Comment: Hey, that was stupidly easy. Thank you. I added your comment as an answer so I can make this as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an item template. File + Export Template. –  Hans Passant